# Shipping Table Rates on Weight for local area and for States. How do I set up using Shipping Table

Tags: shipping, table-rates

I'm creating csv file for shipping in Magento.

Shipping Rule is:

1. If Sub-Total is above Rs.800 , Shipping will be free.
2. If Sub Total is below Rs.800 and
    weight is between 1-250gm  , shipping will Rs 13. for local city 
    weight is between 1-250gm  , shipping will Rs 15. for Gujarat State

I have create something like this

```
Country Region/State    Zip/Postal Code     Weight (and above)  Shipping Price
IND          Gujarat        380%                 1                  13
IND          Gujarat         *                   1                  15
```

here zip code for local city is (380001,380002.....380085)

My Question is :

1. How can I set shipping charge for local ? Whether it is possible using zip code, what format is correct ?
2. I have free shipping enable from configuration of Shipping Method. But when Sub total exceeds from Rs.800 , It show radio button. how can I remove table rate if amount is going to above Rs.800

Output something like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Free Shipping.   You can set it as the shopping cart rule and disable the "Free Shipping" method at all.  It solves the first issue.

[image: Free Shipping]

For the second issue, you probably need advanced **shipping table rates** module, there are a few of them at the magento connect.

Comment: I am using webshop matrix rate for shipment, how can i give free shipping based on zipcodes?